# Are all adjoints lattice homomorphisms?

Tags: proof-verification, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators, vector-lattices

Obviously something must be wrong in the following reasoning proving that **any linear operator $T:X\to Y$ between Banach lattices has a lattice homomorphic adjoint**: $\forall a,b\in E':$
$$T'(a\wedge b)=(T'a)\wedge(T'b)$$
if and only if $\forall x\in E:$
$$(T'(a\wedge b))x=((T'a)\wedge(T'b))x$$
if and only if (by definition adjoint)
$$(a\wedge b)T x=((T'a)\wedge(T'b))x$$
if and only if (by definition $\wedge$ on dual $E'$)
$$(a T x)\wedge(b T x)=((T'a)x)\wedge((T'b)x)$$
if and only if (by definition adjoint)
$$(a T x)\wedge(b T x)=(a T x)\wedge(b T x)$$
which is always true (and the same logic holds for $\vee$). Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Banach lattices, but your "definition" of $\wedge$ on $E'$ seems very suspect...the pointwise meet of two linear functionals will usually not be linear.

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right, thank you! I will post the definition as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the lattice structure on the dual is (see [1], Proposition II.4.2):

$$(a\wedge b)(x)=\sup\left\{f(y)+g(z):y+z=x,y\geq 0,z\geq 0\right\}$$

which is not the 'pointwise meet' as I assumed in the question.

```
[1] Banach Lattices and Positive Operators, Schaefer
```

Comment: This is still not the correct definition.  You need also to assume that $y \ge 0$ and $z \ge 0$.  Also note that there are many Proposition 4.2's in the [cited book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65970-6); it seems that you mean Proposition II.4.2.