# Adjoint lattice homomorphic if surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, vector-lattices

**Is the adjoint of a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ between Banach lattices, always lattice homomorphic if $T$ is surjective?**

This is my proof but I really doubt this is true: $\forall a,b\in Y'$ and $\forall x\in X$:

$$T'(a\wedge b)x=((T'a)\wedge(T'b))x$$
iff (definition adjoint)
$$(a\wedge b)T x=((T'a)\wedge(T'b))x$$
iff (definition $\wedge$ on $Y'$ and definition $\wedge$ on $X'$)
$$\sup\{a y+b z:T x=y+z\}=\sup\{(T'a)y+(T'b)z:x=y+z\}$$
iff (definition adjoint)
$$\sup\{a y+b z:T x=y+z\}=\sup\{a T y+b T z:x=y+z\}$$
iff (change of variables)
$$\sup\{a y +b(T x - y):y \in Y\}=\sup\{a T y+b T (x-y):y \in X\}$$
iff (remove constant term)
$$\sup\{a y+b y:y \in Y\}=\sup\{a T y+b T y:y \in X\}$$
which holds if $T$ is surjective. **Or even when $T$ only has dense range?**

(I made a small mistake in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714726/are-all-adjoints-lattice-homomorphisms), but this result still seems way too strong)

Comment: I do not think that your definition of the meet of linear operators can be correct.  In particular, the suprema you write down never exist unless the operators being 'met' are the same.  Indeed, if it did exist, then we would have that $(a \wedge b)(x) = a(x) + \sup \{(b - a)(z) : z \in Y\} = b(x) + \sup \{(a - b)(y) : y \in Y\}$ for all $x \in Y$; but the two sets being 'supremed' are the same.

Comment: Aha; your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714726/are-all-adjoints-lattice-homomorphisms) points to the correct definition, appearing in Proposition II.4.2 of [Schaefer - Banach lattices and positive operators](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-65970-6_2).  As I have now indicated [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714726/are-all-adjoints-lattice-homomorphisms#comment3502797_1714875), you are omitting from the definition of the meet the requirement that $y, z \ge 0$, which invalidates your fourth ("change of variables") step.

Comment: @LSpice, sorry for my sloppy mistakes and thanks for pointing them out!